# Why does the node inspector not start when I am using nodemon and ts-node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, nodemon, ts-node

I have a simple node server written in typescript. My package.json is configured as:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc",
  "dev": "nodemon --watch src/**/* -e ts,json --exec ts-node ./src/server.ts",
  "debug": "nodemon  --verbose  --watch src/**/* -e ts,json --exec ts-node --inspect ./src/server.ts"
},
```

When I run `npm run dev` nodemon will launch the server and restart it when any changes are made.

```
[02/28/18 20:45:53]  npm run dev

> pq-api@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\joe\pq\pq-api
> nodemon --watch src/**/* -e ts,json --exec ts-node ./src/server.ts

[nodemon] 1.15.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: src/**/*
[nodemon] starting `ts-node ./src/server.ts`
initializing config to development
info: PQ-API running on port 3000
```

However, when I run `npm run debug` (so I can attach a debugger) It looks like it begins to start, but just hangs forever

```
[02/28/18 20:39:30]  npm run debug

> pq-api@1.0.0 debug C:\Users\joe\pq\pq-api
> nodemon  --verbose  --watch src/**/* -e ts,json --exec ts-node --inspect ./src/server.ts

[nodemon] 1.15.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] or send SIGHUP to 10156 to restart
[nodemon] watching: src/**/*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[nodemon] starting `ts-node --inspect ./src/server.ts`
[nodemon] spawning
[nodemon] child pid: 13344
[nodemon] watching 12 files
```

That is all the output has. The script is never executed; the server never starts up, and the inspector is never available to connect to.

**node 8.94**
**nodemon 1.15.1**
**ts-node 5.0.0**
**typescript 2.7.2**

Comment: Try giving a port to the `inspect` like `--inspect=0.0.0.0:9200`

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed that did it. Please leave an answer and I will accept it! :)

Comment: In my case downgrade to version 3.3.0 helps. But I did not try anything between 3.3.0 and 5.0.1, maybe 3.3.0 is not the latest working version.

Comment: Security implication of `--inspect=0.0.0.0:9200`: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#exposing-the-debug-port-publicly-is-unsafe and `--inspect=9200` would suffice for most situations.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

With ts-node 5.0.0 you no longer pass the `--inspect flag` the same way.  The suggested way is `node --inspect -r ts-node/register path/to/ts`.  For example:

`nodemon --watch src/**/* -e ts,json --exec node --inspect-brk -r ts-node/register src/app.ts`

see https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/537

Comment: As of January 2022, version 10.4.0, the documentation still points to this method. "If you need to use advanced node.js CLI arguments (e.g. --inspect), use them with node -r ts-node/register instead of ts-node's CLI." from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node

Answer (score 3):

I made changes using some of the info above as mine just didn't seem to work and the change I made did resolve the problem.

From `"start": "tsnd --inspect -- src/app.local.ts"`
To: `"start": "node --inspect -r ts-node/register src/app.local.ts"`

Answer (score 2):

Provide location and port to the inspect option like:

```
--inspect=0.0.0.0:9200
```

Comment: Security implication: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#exposing-the-debug-port-publicly-is-unsafe

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed this problem by writing nodemon.json file like this :

```
{
  "restartable": "rs",
  "ignore": [".git", "node_modules/**/node_modules"],
  "verbose": true,
  "execMap": { // [A]
    "ts": "node --require ts-node/register"
  },
  "watch": ["src/"],
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development"
  },
  "ext": "js,json,ts"
}
```

ref : https://dev.to/oieduardorabelo/nodejs-with-typescript-debug-inside-vscode-and-nodemon-23o7

Answer (score 1):

I am using PHP Storm and the previous answer of @user60456 works like a charm for me.

With some changes, I was able to run debug mode using **dotenv** with multiple env files in PHP Storm as well.

**package.json**

```
"start:dev": "nodemon --watch src/**/* -e ts,json --exec node --inspect-brk -r ts-node/register -r dotenv/config local.ts dotenv_config_path=./.env.development",
```

where **local.ts** is the file where my *app.listen()* is.

Then, I had to create a new **Run configuration (Attach to Node.js/Chrome)** with:

- **host**: localhost
- **port**: 9229
- **Attach to**: Chrome or Node.js > 6.3 started with --inspect

Then select the root folder in **Remote URLs of local files** tab and set the **Remote URL** to **/usr/src/app**.

[image]

Now, you can run `npm run start:dev`. You will see the console output:

`Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/...`

You have to run the Nodej.js debug configuration now and wait, until you see the console output:

`Debugger attached.`

[image]

The application is now running in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different issue resulting in the debugger never running. I was running this command,

```
node index.js --inspect=5005
```

instead of this,

```
node --inspect=5005 index.js
```

The flag is supposed to be before the source file.

Comment: This is what solved it for me. spent so many hours on this smh

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it. In your `package.json` update your script to:

```bash
nodemon --inspect ./bin/www.js
```

and in `nodemon.json` add make sure your `execMap` is `requiring` `ts-node/register`:

```json
{
  "execMap": {
    "js": "node --require ts-node/register",
    "ts": "node --require ts-node/register"
  }
}
```